# keras AssertionError: Duplicate registrations for type 'experimentalOptimizer'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to build a Deep Q Learning code for CartPole-v1 game. However I encounter an AssertionError:

```python
AssertionError: Duplicate registrations for type 'experimentalOptimizer'
```

Some of the stacktrace is shown below:

[image: the error]

I upgraded TensorFlow but it didn't work. What should I do to fix it?

#### System Details

- Windows OS
- Spyder IDE
- Anaconda 3 (**base** environment)

Comment: It would be preferable to include the full stack trace as text, rather than as an image. Currently we cannot see what user-level code actually triggered the error.

Answer (score 6):

Same problem : I completely uninstalled the libraries (nightly...), and reinstalled the latest stable version (pip3 install tensorflow)
I'm on linux, don't have your configuration, don't know which libraries are installed.
Anyway I hope this helps.

So : uninstall keras, tensorboard, tensorflow, tensorflow-gpu if it's installed, idem for tb-nightly, keras-nightly, tf-nightly

Re-install without specifications tensorflow, it will take care of needed lib.

Answer (score 4):

1. uninstall:

   - `keras`
   - `keras-nightly`
   - `keras-preprocessing`
   - `tensorboard`
   - `tensorflow`
   - `tb-nightly`
   - `tf-nightly`
2. ```shell
   pip3 install tensorflow
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry this does not help. I tried

```
pip3 uninstall tensorflow absl-py astunparse flatbuffers gast google-pasta grpcio h5py keras keras-preprocessing libclang numpy opt-einsum protobuf setuptools six tensorboard tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem termcolor tf-estimator-nightly typing-extensions wrapt
```

then

```
pip3 install --no-cache-dir tensorflow
```

But the error is still there. I guess after uninstall I need to remove some files manually...

Update: got it. Had to remove .local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras as sudo. Then reinstall helped.