# AssertionError: Duplicate registrations for type 'experimentalOptimizer' when converting ssd model to tflite format

Tags: python, tensorflow, model, anaconda, solid-state-drive

I was trying to convert my trained ssd model to tflite format. But I always face to this below error.

[error I faced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VS5tY.png)

Here is my code:

//----------------------------

import tensorflow as tf

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model("/TensorFlow/workspace/traning_demo/exported-models/my_model/saved_model/")
tflite_model = converter.convert()

with open('tflite_test2.tflite', 'wb') as f:
f.write(tflite_model)

//------------------

Does anyone have solution for this problem? Thank you very much

Best regards

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71104727/) reference help you? Thanks!